# How to save previous product stock quantity in Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I need previous and current stock quantity. For previous I found `woocommerce_product_before_set_stock` hook, that must be right, but it saves current quantity;

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_before_set_stock', function ($product) {
    update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_old_stock_quantity', $product->get_stock_quantity());
});
```

For current i can use just `$product->get_stock_quantity()`. So i need only previous. Help./

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get_post_meta`. to get old stock quantity by using the `_stock` key. Try the below code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_before_set_stock', function ($product) {
    update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_old_stock_quantity', get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_stock', true ) );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**`woocommerce_update_product_stock_query`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.html#source-view.1424) hook found inside the `update_product_stock` and `set_product_stock` methods of the `WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT` class.

> This hook is activated before the product stock quantity update query
> is executed. Through it you will have access to **the previous** and **new
> product stock quantity** *(regardless of the type of operation)*.

Then you can use the `$product` object **to get the old stock quantity of the product** *(since the product is not yet updated)*, via `$product->get_stock_quantity()`.

> The possible operations are: `set`, `increase` or `decrease`.

```
// get old and new product stock quantity
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_product_stock_query', 'get_old_and_new_product_quantity_stock', 10, 4 );
function get_old_and_new_product_quantity_stock( $sql, $product_id_with_stock, $new_stock, $operation ) {

    $product            = wc_get_product( $product_id_with_stock );
    $old_stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    $new_stock_quantity = $new_stock;
    
    // run your code

    return $sql;

}
```

**To save the previous product stock quantity as a custom post meta** you can use the following function:

```
// save the previous product stock quantity
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_product_stock_query', 'get_old_and_new_product_quantity_stock', 10, 4 );
function get_old_and_new_product_quantity_stock( $sql, $product_id_with_stock, $new_stock, $operation ) {

    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id_with_stock );
    // save the previous product stock quantity as a custom post meta "_old_stock_quantity"
    update_post_meta( $product_id_with_stock, '_old_stock_quantity', $product->get_stock_quantity() );

    // updates the product stock quantity
    return $sql;

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

---

**FOR INFORMATION**

If the operation was **decrease** and the quantity was **2**, the value of the `$sql` variable would be:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = meta_value -2.000000 WHERE post_id = 14 AND meta_key='_stock'
```

Comment: @DmitrijYakovenko Also I would like to point out that in the description of your question you wrote ***I need previous and current stock quantity.***. This cannot be achieved with the `woocommerce_product_before_set_stock` hook because you have no way of knowing what the new stock quantity of the product will be. You should update the title or description of your question.