# Woocommerce prevent negative variation stock with backorder

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im allowing backorders in my store, but i don't want the stock quantity to be negative.

I tried to fix this using this :

```
add_action('woocommerce_variation_set_stock', 'avoid_negative_stock', 10, 1);
function avoid_negative_stock( $product ) {
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_variation_set_stock' ) >= 2 )
        return;
    if($product->get_stock_quantity() < 0){
        $product->set_stock_quantity(0);
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work :/

Can anyone help me up with that ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**`woocommerce_update_product_stock_query`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.html#source-view.1424) hook.
In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66991612/10447197) you can find a solution.

> Keep in mind that it's not a good idea to force product inventory
> management.

I'll give you an example:

1. You have enabled backorders for a product that has a stock of **1 quantity**.
2. A customer places an order for that product by purchasing **3 quantities**.
3. With your rule the product will have **the stock quantity at zero** *(instead of -2)*
4. The order is canceled or refunded and **the product stock quantity is reset to 3** *(instead of 1)*

This is multiplied by all orders of the same product which for any reason are canceled and/or refunded. *The product stock quantity will no longer be reliable.*

Just be aware of it.

That said, **you can disable negative stock quantity** like this:

```
// disables the negative product stock quantity
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_product_stock_query', 'disable_negative_stock_quantity', 10, 4 );
function disable_negative_stock_quantity( $sql, $product_id_with_stock, $new_stock, $operation ) {

    global $wpdb;

    // if the new stock quantity is negative, it sets zero
    if ( $new_stock < 1 ) {
        $new_stock = 0;
    }

    // generates SQL with the stock quantity at zero
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE {$wpdb->postmeta} SET meta_value = %f WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key='_stock'", wc_stock_amount( $new_stock ), $product_id_with_stock );
    
    return $sql;

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: I believe that your code updates the product stock and not the variation stock quantity. Isn't it ? Anyway i just tried it with Code Snippets plugin but it's not working :/

Comment: Edit: just tried to put it on functions.php of my theme and it's working. Why isn't it working with Code Snippets ? :o

Comment: The stock quantity and the variation stock quantity are the same. Using the `woocommerce_update_product_stock_query` hook you already have the product id (it can be a simple product or a product variation). I have tested it and it works. Unfortunately I don't know why it doesn't work with the Code Snippets plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `update_product_stock` and `read_stock_quantity` Try below code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_variation_set_stock', 'avoid_negative_stock', 10, 1);
function avoid_negative_stock( $product ) {
    
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_variation_set_stock' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    $product_id_with_stock = $product->get_stock_managed_by_id();
    $product_with_stock    = $product_id_with_stock !== $product->get_id() ? wc_get_product( $product_id_with_stock ) : $product;
    $data_store            = WC_Data_Store::load( 'product' );
    $stock_quantity        = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    if( $stock_quantity < 1 ){

        $stock_quantity = 0;

        // Update the database.
        $new_stock = $data_store->update_product_stock( $product_id_with_stock, $stock_quantity, 'set' );

        // Update the product object.
        $data_store->read_stock_quantity( $product_with_stock, $new_stock );
    
        $product->save();
    }

}
```